# Class in select_tag not loading on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got the following select tag:

```
= select_tag 'rights', options_for_select([["User", "user"], ["Editor", "editor"], ["Admin", "admin"],], current_rights), {class: 'selectpicker'}
```

The select tag works, but for some reason the class isn't loading when I load the page for the first time.

However when I refresh the page, the class does load.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the javascript code where your bootstrap-select is initialized ?

Comment: `//= require bootstrap-select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, at the bottom of your `application.js` :

```
$(document).on('page:load', function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```